# Ext-json is missing in composer.json

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5, phpstorm

I cannot use `json_encode()` function in my Laravel project, it says ext-json is missing in composer.json. Any help please!

Answer (score 36):

For this problem, JetBrains [PHP Storm blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/06/phpstorm-2018-2-eap-182-3458-35/)  provide a solution

```
"ext-json": "*"
```

> It is important to list PHP extensions your project requires. Not all PHP installations are created equal: some may miss extensions you may consider as standard (such as ext-mysqliwhich is not installed by default in Fedora/CentOS minimal installation systems). Failure to list required PHP extensions may lead to a bad user experience: Composer will install your package without any errors but it will then fail at run-time. The show — platform command lists all PHP extensions available on your system. You may use it to help you compile the list of extensions you use and require. Alternatively you may use third party tools to analyze your project for the list of extensions used.

[Read more here](https://medium.com/@luis.barros.nobrega/ext-json-is-missing-in-composer-json-what-is-this-700a1fcad966)

Comment: still I cannot use json_encode in phpstorm

Comment: Adding ext-json to composer.json only helps you control your project; reminding you to install that particular extension. You have to install this php extension yourself, to your system. Composer can't help with that.